# .click in jquery not worked ? in my menu ,the html code GET by $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

i wrote showDataSubject() >function using javascript to fetch data from sql table.by jquery.ajax()

```
function showDataSubject() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "subject.aspx/showDataSubject",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg) {
                    // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                    $('#PanelSubjectMenu').html(msg.d);
                }
            });
        }
```

c# method

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string showDataSubject()
    {
        SqlToXml sqlToXml = new SqlToXml();
       // sqlToXml.CreateSubject();
        return sqlToXml.CreateSubjectTreeViewClient();
       // htmlShowData = sqlToXml.CreateSubjectTreeViewClient();          

    }
```

Saved in fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/H5guu/

but the click() method did not work.(in the fiddle it worked correctly)

but in my application it did NOT work.

```
$('#PanelSubjectMenu  span').click(function() {
            $('#subjectTree span').css('color', 'black');
            $(this).css('color', 'red');
        });
```

What's the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use delagation for jquery 1.7+:

```
 $('#PanelSubjectMenu').on('click','span',function() {
                $('#subjectTree span').css('color', 'black');
                $(this).css('color', 'red');
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess its because your html code is dynamic. So you need to bind it like:

```
$('#PanelSubjectMenu  span').live('click', function() {
    $('#subjectTree span').css('color', 'black');
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

for older versions of jquery    (<1.7)
    OR
for jquery 1.7+

```
$(document).on('click', '#PanelSubjectMenu  span', function() {
    $('#subjectTree span').css('color', 'black');
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```